# How to add a prop to super React component in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm going to write a HOC-liked function to add a "visible" prop to the React Component. When the visible prop is set to false, the `render` function just `return null`, the state must be kept.

I have written a JavaScript version but still can not rewrite it in TypeScript, because I can not found a way to add a prop to the super React component.

Followed my attempt:

```
import React from "react";

interface IVisibleProps {
  /** @default true */
  visible?: boolean;
}

const withVisible = <P>(Component: React.ComponentClass<P>): React.ComponentClass<P & IVisibleProps> => (
  class VisibleComponent extends Component {
    public static defaultProps = { visible: true, ...Component.defaultProps };
    public static displayName = Component.displayName || Component.name;

    public render() {
      return this.props.visible ? super.render() : null;
    }
  }
);

export default withVisible;
```

I still can not find a way to pass the typing check. Especially how to add `IVisibleProps` to the generic `P` of the returned Component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little odd fix:

```
function withVisible<P>(
  Component: React.ComponentClass<P>
): ComponentClass<P & IVisibleProps> {
  return class VisibleComponent extends Component {
    public static defaultProps: Partial<P & IVisibleProps> = {
      visible: true,
      ...Component.defaultProps!
    };
    public static displayName = Component.displayName || Component.name;
    public readonly props!: Readonly<P & IVisibleProps>;
    public render() {
      return this.props.visible ? super.render() : null;
    }
  };
```

`public readonly props!: Readonly<P & IVisibleProps>;` lets us extend props.

`...Component.defaultProps!` actually is a dirty hack: `defaultProps` can be undefined, in that case `{...Component.defaultProps}` has an empty `{}` signature with is not suite `Partial<P>` required by the interface. That is why it does not work, but it is just poor typings and there is nothing to worry about, so we could bypass check with the `!`

Comment: Did you mean `class VisibleComponent extends Component` which `Component` is the argument?

Comment: @Gerhut, yes, sorry for the mistake